# NGINX RTMP stream output to HDMI

Tags: raspbian, streaming, nginx

I have a NGINX rtmp streaming sever. I can connect to this server with OBS and be able to stream. Is it possible to connect a monitor to the raspberry pi and the connected monitor will show the stream? Currently im doing this with the VLC (There I type in the stream URL). But is it possible that the monitor *automatically* shows the stream? Like configuring the streaming server so it will output the stream to a monitor connected with a HDMI cable?

I am using the raspberry pi 3 Model B V1.2.
I made the streaming server based on [this tutorial](https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2020/01/nginx-with-rtmp-on-raspberry-pi-as-a-streaming-server-for-obs/).

Comment: so, you want VLC to be started by nginx when it starts receiving a stream? or, at least nginx notifying "something" that a stream is present

Comment: What I want is that nginx outputs the stream to a connected monitor.

Comment: nginx is a web server, so it can't do that

Comment: but there is an `exec_push` directive in the config that you can use to start a program

Comment: You can do it using OMXplayer. Check out this tutorial - https://aaronparecki.com/2020/09/07/7/raspberry-pi-streaming-server

Comment: I finnaly can do this with this tutorial: https://aaronparecki.com/2020/09/07/7/raspberry-pi-streaming-server